# Best Practices on toString() - Any pitfalls on performance/ memory consumption when override toString()

Tags: c#

We are building web-API services in C#. This API service calls another downstream stream service using HttpClient. Before making any PUT or PATCH to downstream services, we are serializing the request payload using the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method. We add a debugging/logging statement calling `JsonConvert.SerializeObject("RequestObjectToSerialize>")`. Here, `RequestObjectToSerialize` is a class that holds request payload information.

Instead of calling `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` at every time to log. We override `RequestPayload` Class's `ToString()` and have `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this)` return the serialized format of the object, which is of type string.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
}
```

I'm curious to know if there are any side effects or pitfalls to overriding `ToString()` and serializing objects into strings. Any runtime performance issues and memory issues

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here. Are you worried about a performance penalty because you're wrapping serialization with the `ToString()` override?

Comment: `ToString` is also used to display the value in the debugger, so `ToString` should return a short value that represents your entity. One pitfall might be that `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);` throws an exception. What about passing a format? You can do your serializing if e.g "S" has been passed as the format, but you should also implent the [expected behaviour](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-7.0#notes-to-inheritors) if no format is specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be basically no performance difference between calling Serialize explicitly or inside the overwritten ToString. However, you possibly have less control over where ToString is called.

Consider, for example, you would serialize a object that holds a reference to your Request object. In that case, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RequestObject) would be called, where as if you hadn't had overwritten the ToString method, only a string representation of the instance would be printed.

If you have the possibility, you could consider storing the generated JSON to a private string member so that it can be reused. Be sure, however to check if the state of the object hasn't been modified ("dirty").

This obviously only helps if you prefer losing memory over losing CPU Time. (Also the effect varies based on the amount of data you need to serialize / the "size" of the Request object)